# C# .NET 4.5 activity-based authorization WebForms (not MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, webforms, asp.net-authorization

Currently I’m trying to implement activity-based authorization in my webform application. In my application you have different roles: Admin, manager, employee, and trainee.

The application communicates with my database through my BLL (business logic layer) and what I’m trying to do, is have authorization on method level in the BLL for all the reader and manager files for all my entities, like so:

```
[Authorize(Activity = "CreateUser")]
public static void InsertUser( ... )

[Authorize(Activity = "UpdateEmployee")]
public static void UpdateEmployee( ... )
```

For every method I want a CRUD activity and in the database I want to tell which roles gets to do what activity, or something that´s a lookalike like this.

Role-based security is not an option, besides for logging in, because a trainee for example is not allowed to insert or delete any data, except for one entity. So I need a permission/activity based authorization in my webforms.

Currently all I can find are solutions for MVC and .NET Core, but not any for the webforms, or the posts are from 2011 ish which don't really offer a solution, and I wonder if anyone has any new ideas or solutions as of this time.

In my project I make use of FormsAuthentication, and in my webconfig file I autorize specific roles and paths for specific roles. But this won’t cut it. I also make use of the Application_OnPostAuthenticateRequest in the global file with the FormsIdentity with my custom principal class which makes use of the IIDentity and IPrincipal.

Also, my AddEdit pages are the same page, and based on the querystring passed in the URL, like a userId, or employeeId, the save button decides whether it's an insert or update. So this is the reason why I need auth on methods.

So my question, does anyone know a pattern that I can actually implement in asp.net 4.5 webforms that gets permission or activity based authorization without having to hardcode everything so it's more future proof?

Comment: **Roles** exists from long time ago in ASP.NET, you might take a look to them (first hit on Google: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5k850zwb.aspx, I bet there are much better pages out there)

Comment: But I need activity based authentication, not role based. There is a big difference. I got role based authentocation already implemented, but it doesn't fit the needs for the application. So that's why I am looking for activity-based auth on method level.

Comment: What's the difference? Imagine to have these roles: CreateUser, UpdateEmployee and so on (user might have more than one role). I'd go one step further and I'd introduce a distinction between _roles_ and _permissions_. An activity might require one or more of them. Another step further: use a simple expression parser (like NCalc) to parse the authorization expression (something like `"[administrators group]" or [create employee]"`, in complex scenarios you might not want to have a different privilege for each single action - a nightmare to maintain - but a mixed role-based approach).

Comment: Hm yeah, I understand the point of just making a lot of roles, and giving a user multiple roles to do certain actions. But how would you go on implementing it so a method gets denied then? I prefer not to write code in every single method to do a role check of the current user and if he doesn't have to role to redirect the user or something. And I'm not sure what you mean exactly by the NCalc parser to parse authorization expressions.

Comment: Note that also MVC [Authorization] works with roles. Yes, you add one role for each privilege you want to grant. If you don't want to add this logic in each call then you might consider to use an AOP approach. NCalc is just an example of an easy to use parser for simple expressions. It might be useful for methods that requires more than one _role_ (X and Y and Z), one role from a set (X or Y or Z) or complex rules (for example `[Administrator] or ([Editor] and [Business] and not [Trainee])`). How to check? Depends where this logic is...

Comment: I have never done Aspect Oriented Programming before, I am gonna look into it. Have found some sources and I'll experiment with it. Once I got a solution, I'll post is down below.

Comment: Adriano, I wanted to thank you, you made me look at the problem from a different angel!

Comment: You welcome, sometimes we really need a _rubber duck_! ;)